# React conditionally render send prop to child

Tags: reactjs

How can i conditionally send a prop to a child component. Ex:

```
<ProfilePage id={id} name={name} data={data} />
```

In the ProfilePage component data is optional and handles it accordingly. If data is empty, I dont want to send the prop to the component.

Theoretically like so:

```
<ProfilePage id={id} name={name} {if data then data={data}} />
```

Comment: Render the ProfilePage conditionally, instead of putting an if statement in the component. Put an external if statement and render the ProfilePage component according.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure of a terse way to make the syntax, but you can create an empty object, add the conditional props on there based on criteria, and then spread them on:

```
const additionalProps = {};

if (data) {
    additionProps.data = data;
}

<ProfilePage id={id} name={name} {...additionalProps} />
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, React encourages you to write components that accept `null` or `undefined` values for props and treat them as if they were not present.

```
<ProfilePage id={id} name={name} data={null} />
```

But if you absolutely *must* not pass `data` when its undefined, you can use a messy ternary.

```
<ProfilePage id={id} name={name} {...(data ? {data} : null)} />
```